# Reverse cumulative sum by groups in R with multiple group variable

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr, cumsum

I have data with three variables: date, age group, and cumulative doses of a drug. There are multiple observations per day (one for each age group). I need to preserve the number of rows and variables as in the original data, but also add a fourth variable that represents the actual number of doses administered to the relevant group on the relevant date.

I've tried the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958446/reverse-cumulative-sum-by-group), but have had no luck. I get warnings about the mutate function introducing NAs. The code doesn't error out, but the numbers I get in the new variable are not correct. Some of them are NAs, like the warning says, and some are even negative. I think it might have to do with the fact that there are two variables I think I need to group by and neither is numeric, but I'm not sure. I tried coercing the group variables to numeric before using the solutions on the other SO post, but had the same issues with the results.

Here is a dummy dataset with similar characteristics as mine:

```
structure(list(test_dates = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17897, 
17897, 17897, 17898, 17898, 17898, 17898, 17898, 17899, 17899, 
17899, 17899, 17899, 17900, 17900, 17900, 17900, 17900, 17901, 
17901, 17901, 17901, 17901, 17902, 17902, 17902, 17902, 17902, 
17903, 17903, 17903, 17903, 17903, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17904, 
17904, 17905, 17905, 17905, 17905, 17905, 17906, 17906, 17906, 
17906, 17906), class = "Date"), test_ages = structure(c(1L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L
), .Label = c("<18", "18-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50+"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), cumudose = c(50, 200, 300, 400, 20, 60, 220, 317, 
450, 28, 90, 330, 350, 460, 38, 150, 400, 400, 500, 50, 175, 
453, 429, 574, 69, 182, 491, 474, 601, 102, 205, 506, 491, 682, 
176, 235, 516, 568, 821, 199, 250, 525, 596, 850, 260, 294, 533, 
667, 888, 277)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first 10 rows of the data frame as it currently stands looks like this:

| test_dates | test_ages | cumudose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | <18 | 50 |
| 2019-01-01 | 50+ | 200 |
| 2019-01-01 | 30-39 | 300 |
| 2019-01-01 | 18-29 | 400 |
| 2019-01-01 | 40-49 | 20 |
| 2019-01-02 | <18 | 60 |
| 2019-01-02 | 50+ | 220 |
| 2019-01-02 | 30-39 | 317 |
| 2019-01-02 | 18-29 | 450 |
| 2019-01-02 | 40-49 | 28 |

I would like the data to look like this after the new variable is added:

| test_dates | test_ages | cumudose | numdose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | <18 | 50 | 50 |
| 2019-01-01 | 50+ | 200 | 200 |
| 2019-01-01 | 30-39 | 300 | 300 |
| 2019-01-01 | 18-29 | 400 | 400 |
| 2019-01-01 | 40-49 | 20 | 20 |
| 2019-01-02 | <18 | 60 | 10 |
| 2019-01-02 | 50+ | 220 | 20 |
| 2019-01-02 | 30-39 | 317 | 17 |
| 2019-01-02 | 18-29 | 450 | 50 |
| 2019-01-02 | 40-49 | 28 | 8 |

Let me know if I can provide any additional information!

Comment: You are perhaps looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846547/calculate-difference-between-values-in-consecutive-rows-by-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need the `diff`erence

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>% 
   group_by(test_ages) %>% 
   mutate(numdose = c(first(cumudose), diff(cumudose))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 50 x 4
   test_dates test_ages cumudose numdose
   <date>     <ord>        <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01 <18             50      50
 2 2019-01-01 50+            200     200
 3 2019-01-01 30-39          300     300
 4 2019-01-01 18-29          400     400
 5 2019-01-01 40-49           20      20
 6 2019-01-02 <18             60      10
 7 2019-01-02 50+            220      20
 8 2019-01-02 30-39          317      17
 9 2019-01-02 18-29          450      50
10 2019-01-02 40-49           28       8
# … with 40 more rows
```

---

or do the difference between the `lag` and the current values

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(test_ages) %>% 
   mutate(numdose = coalesce(cumudose  - lag(cumudose), cumudose)) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 50 x 4
   test_dates test_ages cumudose numdose
   <date>     <ord>        <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01 <18             50      50
 2 2019-01-01 50+            200     200
 3 2019-01-01 30-39          300     300
 4 2019-01-01 18-29          400     400
 5 2019-01-01 40-49           20      20
 6 2019-01-02 <18             60      10
 7 2019-01-02 50+            220      20
 8 2019-01-02 30-39          317      17
 9 2019-01-02 18-29          450      50
10 2019-01-02 40-49           28       8
# … with 40 more rows
```